# Firebase Cloud Functions Generate Push ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Firebase cloud function that creates a "Multi-player Room" object in the Real-time Database for my multi-player game. I use `databaseReference.push()` to write the room in the database with a unique ID, but I need to get that ID and store in the room object too.
What I get:

```
{
   multiplayer_games:{
      -SOME_ID:{
         some_value:***,
         some_other_value:***
      }
   }
}
```

What I need:

```
{
   multiplayer_games:{
      -SOME_ID:{
         id:-SOME_ID,
         some_value:***,
         some_other_value:***
      }
   }
}
```

So how can I get that random push ID and use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate a key you can use:

```
let key = admin.database().ref().push().key;
```